# Laravel 8 fresh installation livewire directory does not exist

Tags: laravel-8

I have a fresh installation of laravel 8 and I have also installed livewire but when I register I get the error

```
 The "C:\xampp\htdocs\sms\app/Http/Livewire" directory does not exist. (View: 
 C:\xampp\htdocs\sms\resources\views\layouts\app.blade.php) (View: 
 C:\xampp\htdocs\sms\resources\views\layouts\app.blade.php)
```

I followed the instructions in the laravel documentation page.
What could I be doing wrong?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I guess you did run the third command `php artisan jetstream:install inertia` too, that could have removed livewire, Try rerunning the second command `php artisan jetstream:install livewire` to install livewire then run `npm install` followed by `npm run dev`

Comment: dose running npm install and npm run dev necessary? or they are optional.

Comment: @eraufi the output of `php artisan jetstream:install livewire` indicates that npm should be run so I would think yes.

On my broken upgraded system when I ran a fresh livewire install too many files got updated and I had to revert my application.

Answer (score 5):

Create a new livewire component to generate those directories. Reinstalling did not create them for me.

```
php artisan make:livewire counter
```

Answer (score 0):

If you haven't started anything yet, just **re-install laravel** and run the command **php artisan jetstream:install inertia** cause there's an error when reverting back from livewire to inertia.